# Read from a CSV file, multiply two columns, and then write back to the CSV file in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have created csv file with values.I am able to read rows but don't know how to access individual values of a column.

```
require "csv"
CSV.open("file.csv", "w") 
do |csv|
    csv << ["val1", "val2","mul"]
    csv << ["53", "27"]
    csv<<["32","20"]
end
```

Comment: You can write to a new CSV file instead of the original one. If you don't want to keep the original one, you can just delete it, then rename your newly create CSV file.

Comment: You should probably show what you've tried so far.

Comment: No,I have to write the calculated value in a new column of same csv file.

Comment: Well, you can do this in very low-level file manipulation. You can manually track your cursor position, move content forward/backward. But trust me, this is very very error prone. You never want to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to ignore the header row if you have one. But the general idea is this:

```
CSV.open('dest.csv', 'w') do |csv|
  csv << ["val1", "val2","mul"]

  CSV.foreach('source.csv') do |row|
    c1 = row[0]
    c2 = row[1]
    csv << [c1, c2, c1*c2]
  end
end
```

If you have headers, you could do this:

```
CSV.open('dest.csv', 'w') do |csv|
  csv << ["val1", "val2", "mul"]

  CSV.foreach('source.csv', headers: true) do |row|
    c1 = row['val1']
    c2 = row['val2']
    csv << [c1, c2, c1*c2]
  end
end
```

You can use the one below for a non-ruby solution too:

```
awk -F "," '{print $1,$2,$1*$2}' source.csv > dest.csv
```